# Not getting ouput after successful execution of the SQL scripts through powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have to automate one process to get rid of daily effort reduction in our organization. We need to execute multiple scripts on different SQL Server instances and each script contains database name as well.

So initially our client put all the scripts on a particular location and I need to execute each of the scripts and then move the script file to different folder.

After a script got an error, it logged the error and one file has been generated.

After successful execution I need to generate one log file where all the successful results script wise also getting generated. Like when we execute one script in SSMS, after executing the script it generates a message like "1 row affected".

How can I do that?

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "E:\test.sql" -serverinstance ".\Your_Instance_Name" -database "user" | out-File -filepath "E:\result.txt"
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 0):

The "1 row(s) affected" message is generated automatically, unless [set nocount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is specified.

A client application, such as Invoke-SqlCmd, SSMS and sqlcmd, can do whatever with the row count number. SSMS and sqlcmd print it per default, Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't seem to do that. This is not a bug, though it's certainly a bit surprising.

The simple approach is to issue an explicit select for  [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Like so,

```
insert mydb.schema.table(column1, column2....) values(...); select @@rowcount;
```

Or, use `sqlcmd.exe` instead.

Comment: Ok Sqlcmd is good for that I can get the result as expected but through sqlcmd its not throughing the error  message if any sql script has an error , please guide me how I can capture the error if any script has an error .

Comment: @dipanjanchakraborty That would be a separate question. Click the accept answer and post a new one about how to handle errors.