# sqlcmd function not throwing the error message if any sql script has an error executing through powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation

Used Sqlcmd function on PowerShell script for multiple SQL scripts execution to get the result as ssms output but through sqlcmd it's not throwing the error message or not able to write catch method if any SQL script has an error, please guide me how I can capture the error if any script has an error.

using Invoke-Sqlcmd command I am not able to capture the script execution output as SSMS has given after execution of any update or insert statement like "1 Rows affected" ,so I need to use sqlcmd command to execute the sql scripts and now all the scripts records are captured but on Invoke-sqlcmd command if any error in the sql scripts its going to the catch block and showing the error but when I am using SQLCMD if there is any error in SQL script it will not go to catch block it statys in the try block and continue .

So please help now how I can capture and move it to catch block or I can capture the error as I have done before using Invoke-SQLCMD command.

this is a continuation of this link :
[Not getting ouput after successful execution of the SQL scripts through powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998712/not-getting-ouput-after-successful-execution-of-the-sql-scripts-through-powershe/55998947?noredirect=1#comment98813323_55998947)

Here is my code block and it's not going to catch block :

Try
                    {

```
                  #$result = "Sqlcmd.exe -S $InstanceNAme -d $dbname -Q ""Insert into [DUR2_A].[dbo].[emp_info] values(1,'Ram','Kolkata')"""
                  #Invoke-Expression $result | Out-File filesystem::$ScriptOutPutpath$scriptfilesc$out
                  sqlcmd -S $InstanceNAme -i $scriptfiles1 -o $ScriptOutPutpath$scriptfilesc$out -m1
                  Move-Item filesystem::$scriptfiles1 filesystem::$Scriptbackuppath


                }
                catch
                {


                     $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                     $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
                     echo "Error for $scriptfilesc - $($_.Exception.Message)" | Out-File filesystem::$error_log$scriptfilesc$errorout
                     Send-MailMessage -from test@test.com -To IO-SD.GP.test@test.com -SmtpServer mailrelay.test.com -Subject "DUR Error" -Body "Script $scriptfilesc has not been executed becasue of Error Message $ErrorMessage.Kindly check the attachd script and error message" -Attachments filesystem::$error_log$scriptfilesc$errorout,filesystem::$scriptfiles1
                     Move-Item filesystem::$scriptfiles1 filesystem::$Scriptbackuppath


                }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show an example of an error you'd like to catch. Table definition, sample insert command and the like.

Comment: Since you added nearly no information in your question I can only guess that you're (maybe) using `invoke-sqlcmd`. If so, did you set the `-ErrorAction` to `Stop`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell:how to catch the error cause by invoke-sqlcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766250/powershellhow-to-catch-the-error-cause-by-invoke-sqlcmd)